# Creating a regular expression that matched a group of out of order values

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse the following using regex. The groups contain a series of values, and are always separated by a new line. But, not all values will always be present, and the order isn't always the same.

```
abc = 111
def = 122
ijk = 133

def = 222
abc = 211
ijk = 233

abc = 311
ijk = 333
```

Here's what I have so far, but it only works if every value is present and in the right order

```
(?:abc = (?<abc>\d*))\n(?:def = (?<def>\d*))\n(?:ijk = (?<ijk>\d*))
```

I can add a bunch of `|` to account for the various possible ordering, but that creates a huge mess, and makes the expression barely readable.

Comment: What programming language do you use ?

Comment: Why not just use [`([a-z]+) = (\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/QCrbYr/1) instead of naming your groups and access capture group 1 for the name?

Comment: @Jan, I am using c#

Comment: @ctwheels, that won't work, because I won't be able to tell group1 from group2.

Comment: How so: 1 != 2?

Comment: How does your regex tell the groups apart? What result do you expect? What variable type is your input in?

Answer (score 0):

You need a pattern that matches a single group in any order, and then use `Regex.Matches` to extract each group:

```
var pattern = @"(?:(?:(?:abc = (?<abc>\d+))|(?:def = (?<def>\d+))|(?:ijk = (?<ijk>\d+)))\r\n)+";

var ans = Regex.Matches(src, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(mg => mg.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(g => new { g.Name, g.Value }).ToDictionary(g => g.Name, g => g.Value));
```

I used LINQ to reduce the captures down to a `Dictionary` for each group. You could leave out the `Skip(1)` if you wanted a dictionary entry (key `0`) for the whole group.